# PHP 500px API: Upload an image

Tags: php, api, oauth, 500px

I am using 500px API with PHP, with this PHP API integration: https://github.com/jldavid/500px-php/

However, I am stuck on the same point for some time ago.

I have the following code:

// FHpxOAuth is on 500px-php repository under the folder: [oauth/500px.php](https://github.com/jldavid/500px-php/blob/master/oauth/500px.php)

```
$connection = new FHpxOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$params = array(
    'name' => "Sample name",
    'description' => "Sample description bla bla bla",
    'category' => 18,
    'privacy' => 0,
    'file' => file_get_contents('url for the image')
);
$content  = $connection->post('photos/upload', $params);
```

Probably I am not passing the file on the correct format, because I know it should be multipart/form-data.

Any ideas or documentation about how can I upload a photo?

Answer (score 0):

I think first you must convert your array to Multipart/Form-data with a boundary.
But is not possible with the `file_get_contents(url)`.

I've never used the 500px API, but it's pretty much the same as Twitter

Comment: Yes, however I don't know how to pass a multipart/form-data to the post() function using the functions in FHpxOAuth class.